# Popup list under on click area

Tags: jquery, html, popup, position, cross-browser

Hi, I have some simple popup list, showing once i click on the drop down menu option. Unfortunately that popup is under CSS absolute and without it the popup goes under the page.
 
Also, it shows at different positions in different browsers.

```
 $self.next().bind('click', viewList);

    if (!settings.appendTo) {
      $self.after(createDropdown($self, selectboxCounter));
    } else {
      var offset = $self.parent().offset();

      $(settings.appendTo).append(createDropdown($self, selectboxCounter).css({
        'top': offset.top,
        'left': offset.left,
        'width': 100//'width': $self.parent().width() * 0.8
      }));
    }
  }

  $self.trigger('change');
  selectboxCounter++;
});

// Hide dropdown when click is outside of the input or dropdown
$(document).bind('click', hideDropdown);

$('.sb-custom').find('.sb-select').live('keydown', selectKeypress);
$('.sb-custom').bind('blur', clearKeyStrokes);
$(document).delegate('.sb-dropdown', 'focus', viewList);

return this;
};
```

I want to place the popup at the position of the parent selection, or menu position. And also adjust to different browsers.

Comment: can you jsfiddle your example code ? without it imaging the problem is quite difficult

Comment: Put your HTML and JS on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this problem recently with a widget I was helping develop. The solution we came up with was to have the popup list bound to the document body. With the body as the parent we didn't have to worry about other elements hiding the popup. Then we just positioned it absolutely based on where it was popping down from.

```
var offset = $("#popupFromHere").offset();
$("#popup")
    .appendTo("body")
    .css({
        left: offset.left
        top: offset.top + $this.outerHeight(true)
    });
```